# How to get a new column in pandas based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-class data set with columns:

```
File_name     Label     Value.
abcd          A         74
bwld          B         72
```

I have 4 unique labels and I want to create a new column called 'is_valid' which is a boolean, which assigns a true value to 10% of the data from each label type.
Essentialy I am trying to create a train-val split for 10% of each label and create a column which shows if the row has been used for training or validation so that it will look like this:

```
File_name     Label     Value      is_valid
abcd          A         74           True
bwld          B         72           False
```

How can I do this?

I know that this can be done using train test split but I want to use this for a presentation:)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(file_name, label, 
test_size=0.2, random_state=40, stratify=label)
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val_split = 0.1    

df['is_valid'] = False
for label in df['Label'].unique():
    indexes = df[df['Label']==label].sample(frac=val_split)
    df.loc[(indexes.index.values), 'is_valid'] = True
```

Comment: I have a dataset of 505 points under 4 labels. Your code gives me only 13 validation data points when I should be getting around 50 as my data is balanced.

Comment: @bdvsca yes, sorry, I made a mistake. Check the current edited answer, and please mark it as accepted if it works :)